# MUX Circuit Design with MUX MPC506

Tags: circuit-design, multiplexer

I am designing a watchdog circuit to read a number of 15 signals (analog and digital), so I decided to use [MPC506AU](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mpc506.pdf) as shown in the picture.

First of all, can I supply it with +5 volts and leaving the negative voltage supply pin floating? Is it fine to pass different signal types (analog & digital) without affecting the values of these signals? Can I connect the enable pin and Vref pin to the same power supply? Will the signals affect each other while the Mux turned off?

[image: block diagram]

Comment: These questions should be answered in the datasheet. Which you have not linked to.

Comment: Datasheet link added.

Comment: @CL. here is the datasheet added by samGibson, But still cant find the answers

Comment: Hmm, the datasheet does not answer the questions. Apparently, this mux was designed for different applications. You would have to experiment, or use a different mux with known characteristics.

Comment: @CL. Yes there are not many characteristics to know, and I couldn't find any better mux for my application. :(